# python typings - how to handle optional responses

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a func with return type `(str | None)`

`url = check_file_exists(cloud_path)`

typescript has an AST which is smart enough to know that within the following block the return was indeed NOT `None`. but mypi will complain about this:

`Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[Optional[str], str]", expected "Tuple[str, str]")  [return-value]mypy(error)`

```
        if url != None:
            return url, local_filepath
```

but mypy will complain about this. Is there a way to give the hints some hints?

the full thing looks (simplfied) something like this:

```
    def _get_user_image(self, ) -> tuple[str, str]:
        local_filepath = "some/path"
        cloudpath = "https://some.url"

        url = check_file_exists(cloud_path)

        if url != None:
            return url, local_filepath
```

I could mess up my own return values with an extra `None` optional reply but that's just kicking the problem down the road.

`-> tuple[str | None, str]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is not None`, not `!= None`:

```
def check_file_exists(cloud_path) -> str | None:
    return "foo"

def _get_user_image() -> tuple[str, str]:
    local_filepath = "some/path"
    cloudpath = "https://some.url"

    url = check_file_exists(cloudpath)

    if url is not None:
        return url, local_filepath

    return "foo", "bar"
```

The above code reports no mypy errors, but using `!= None` will fail to narrow the type.

Comment: this fixed it! tx